# How to create the empty 'Icon\r' file for a .dmg from shell script?

Tags: macos, unix, shell, icons, dmg

From shell script, I would like to create the empty 'Icon\r' file for a Mac OS X disk image (dmg), so as the .VolumeIcon.icns icon file is taken into account by the finder; the damn '\r' character is not accepted from the console:

```
touch Icon\r
ls Icon*

> Iconr
```

and other things happen when trying to type `'Icon\r'`, `"Icon\r"` etc., I can't achieve to make it accept "\r" as the typical carriage return required at the end of the file name.

Any idea how to type it?

Thanks

Comment: In fact, this Icon\r file is not necessary, and will not make the ".VolumeIcon.icns" show up as the volume icon. What is necessary is to mark the volume as "iconable" with `SetFile -a C $VOLUMEPATH`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo -e "Icon\\r" | xargs touch
```

Answer (score 5):

I assume the file name should be five characters, the last one being a carriage return. In bash or zsh:

```
touch $'Icon\r'
```

Or you can type the carriage return in the shell: `touch Icon` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> .

Answer (score 0):

In bash, you can open your quotes and type "Icon, then on the following line (your prompt should be a > character) close the quotes.

Comment: oops, the editor box ate part of my comment. I meant: open quotes, type Icon, then press enter without closing quotes.